# Issue was a simple user error; should I delete my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, typographical-error

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427710/sshclient-not-finding-known-hosts-or-id-rsa) a few minutes ago, only to realize the reason I was having trouble picking up my SSH credentials was that I was on the wrong host (shocker!).

I know that many simple solutions are still useful on a Q&A site, but I'm not sure how useful this would be to anyone.

Should I delete this question?  Does this count as a [simple typographical error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I would say yes.

Comment: Questions like that are not useful for future users. No harm in deleting it. And leaving it up may attract downvotes in the future.

Comment: This could be downvoted in the future but in the end it is up to you

Comment: +1 for @yivi. The purpose of this site is to accumulate good answers to good questions for use as a programming reference by others. We probably need another site that just accumulates goofs, so people can learn from others' goofs, but this is not that site.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's up to you - this doesn't seem like a particularly *poor* question, but I don't disagree with you in stating that it's probably not useful for future visitors.

Comment: "I don't disagree with you in stating that it's probably not useful for future visitors" is actually double negative for "I agree that it is useless"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ... unless a third state is possible, like true/false/null.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Did you mean [FileNotFound](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton this is a classical Nerd answer. There is in fact a third state in human interaction: not being rude...